# Spotlight no longer showing me installed applications

Tags: macos, spotlight, monterey

Applications like Finder, Activity Monitor, Terminal, System Preferences, and newly-installed ~/Applications apps are not showing up in Spotlight search results.

In System Preferences > Spotlight, the only items enabled are Applications, Calculator, Conversion, Definition:

[image]

And Privacy only blacklists the Downloads folder.

How can I begin to troubleshoot this issue and get Spotlight to show me all my installed applications again?